# How to write query for this condition

Tags: mysql

I am doing a project for a travel agency. i have to joing 3 tables

- `vehicle_details` which i store all vehicle details
- `rac_details` booked vehicle details
- `owner` vehicle owners details

While booking i need to search the vehicles available in that date range in `rac_details` .

```
      $qry="    SELECT `vehicle_details`.*, `owner`.`owner_name`, `owner`.`id` As owner_id, 
    `rac_details`.`from_date`, `rac_details`.`to_date`, 
    `rac_details`.`vehicle_id`
     FROM (`vehicle_details`)
     LEFT JOIN `rac_details` ON `rac_details`.`vehicle_id`=`vehicle_details`.`id`
     AND `rac_details`.`from_date` NOT BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp 
     AND `rac_details`.`to_date` NOT BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp 
     JOIN `owner` ON `owner`.`id`=`vehicle_details`.`owner_id`
 WHERE `vehicle_details`.`model_id` =  '$model_id' ";
```

By the above query i am getting all vehicle details. when `inner join` `rac_details` i am not able to get the newly added vehicle ie which do not have record in `rac_details`.
Hope anyone can help me

**Edit**

For example i got a booking for Polo with reg no XX-YY-ZZ from feb 27th to march 3. then i need to search whether the vehicle xx-yy-zz is available in that days for that i just searched in my rac_details where i store booked vehicle details.
Then we bought a new vehicle Vento with reg no RR-TT-YY so i added that vehicle in my vehicle_details table and no records will be added to rac_details before the first booking

if i write this query

> ```
>  $qry="   SELECT `vehicle_details`.*, `owner`.`owner_name`, `owner`.`id` As owner_id, 
>     `rac_details`.`from_date`, `rac_details`.`to_date`, 
>     `rac_details`.`vehicle_id`
>      FROM (`vehicle_details`)
>      JOIN `rac_details` ON `rac_details`.`vehicle_id`=`vehicle_details`.`id`
>      AND `rac_details`.`from_date` NOT BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp 
>      AND `rac_details`.`to_date` NOT BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp 
>      JOIN `owner` ON `owner`.`id`=`vehicle_details`.`owner_id`
>  WHERE `vehicle_details`.`model_id` =  '$model_id' ";
> ```

when i book vento for the first time it will not show vento in the list since there is no record in `rac_details` for vento

Comment: At first glance, your SELECT statement seems incredibly long and complicated. Could it be simplified? The more complex any code is, the harder it is to debug. Aim for simplicity where possible, or could the SELECT query be written differently. Are you sure the details are saved to the rac_details table when you book it? What does a SELECT query of rac_details show? Do you need to refresh the table?

Comment: @Borges  i just need to get vehicle list which are available in the given date range. and i am keeping the booked details in the table `rac_details`. the proble is with joining the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it with `NOT IN` the already reserved vehicles:

```
"SELECT `vehicle_details`.*, `owner`.`owner_name`, `owner`.`id` As owner_id, 
`rac_details`.`from_date`, `rac_details`.`to_date`, 
`rac_details`.`vehicle_id`
 FROM (`vehicle_details`)
 JOIN `owner` ON `owner`.`id`=`vehicle_details`.`owner_id`
 WHERE `vehicle_details`.`model_id` =  '$model_id' 
 AND vehicle_details.id NOT IN (
   SELECT rac_details.vehicle_id
   FROM rac_details
   WHERE `rac_details`.`from_date` BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp 
     AND `rac_details`.`to_date` BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp
 )"
```

Comment: No For the first time the rac_details table will be empty. data will be added to this when a vehicle is booked.

Comment: @LimZ, you wrote: "i just need to get vehicle list which are available in the given date range. and i am keeping the booked details in the table rac_details". All vehicles that are not yet booked are available, aren't? So at the beginning the inner select will be empty, so NOT IN will give you all the vehicle ids

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug your code with only the select statement. In what environment are you writing the database? Could you provide an example of the database? Are you using JQuery to call the select statement?

Comment: @Borges and Gavriel please see my edits in my question

Comment: @LimZ, did you try this query? What's wrong with it? Error message? Wrong results?

Comment: First of all sorry for not paying much attention to your answer by wrong assumption. With a slight change it works now. Thank you.. thanks a lot `"(SELECT rac_details.vehicle_id FROM rac_details  WHERE rac_details.from_date  BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp OR rac_details.to_date  BETWEEN $from_timestamp AND $to_timestamp  )" i have chaned one AND statement to OR